# Agrupar faturas em atraso php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Olá, sou iniciante, estou aprendendo a fazer select, e gostaria de receber ajuda dessa maravilhosa comunidade.

Eu preciso pegar apenas as faturas que estão com o status a_vencer de cada aluno, seria mais ou menos agrupar por id as faturas que estão com o status a_vencer.

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada faturas com os seguintes campos: id, id_aluno, valor, vencimento e status onde cada aluno tem várias faturas, cada fatura tem o id do aluno, sendo que algumas faturas estão pagas e outras a vencer, e eu queria fazer um select nessa tabela e localizar os alunos que tem apenas 1 fatura em atraso.

Como eu faria isso? Agradeço a ajuda de todos! Obrigada

Comment: A tabela **faturas** tem as colunas  **id, valor e vencimento**, o status **a_vencer** está armazenado em qual coluna?

Comment: Obrigada por me ajudar! Me desculpe, a tabela faturas tem as colunas id, valor, vencimento e status! Obrigada

Comment: Então o valor armazenado na coluna **status** é a palavra **a_vencer**?

Comment: É assim, as faturas que ainda não foram pagas estão com o status a_vencer, e as faturas pagas estão com o status paga.

Comment: Quais os campos que devem ser selecionados? Todos? da tabela **fatura** mesmo ou da **alunos**?

Comment: Verifique se a resposta é o que você precisa e aceite caso esteja certa.

Answer (score 1):

Para selecionar todas as colunas quando o aluno só tem uma fatura com o status 'a_vencer' é necessário utilizar a função *group by* combinada com *having*.

Segue *query*:

```
SELECT id, id_aluno, valor, vencimento, status
FROM faturas
WHERE status = 'a_vencer'
GROUP BY id_aluno
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Pode ver funcionando neste link do [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3f1739/1).

Answer (score -1):

Não tem porque escrever o nome de cada coluna da tabela se irá pegar todas.
A Query acima não está errada, só há uma redundância desnecessária!

Otimizada:

```
SELECT *
FROM faturas
WHERE status = 'a_vencer'
GROUP BY id_aluno
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```